# Twilio screensharing on localhost in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc, twilio

Currently screensharing on localhost in firefox throws the following error:
`The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context.`.

Here's my code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { mediaSource: 'screen' } })
      .then((stream) => {
            console.log('stream', stream)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
            console.log('err', err)
      })
```

Comment: The version of firefox you're using is important in figuring out what this bug is. In versions before 52, whitelisting was necessary, likewise - if I remember correctly, one needed a self signed cert to make sure any screensharing was over https

Comment: did you change this flag with code? it will be bad choice to let users enable this flag manually! how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using it for testing, setting `media.navigator.permission.disabled` to true in about:config skips the dialog and the error.

Comment: how to change this variable with code? why Firefox doesn't enable this flag by default? it seems it is a bug!

Comment: because it is for testing purposes only -- you do not want a random website to access your camera without your explicit permission ever.

Comment: yes you are right, but I'm trying to share screen only, and fireFox doesn't allow this till I set this flag, what do you think? how to resolve this issue? why Firefox doesn't ask me for permission then?

Comment: could you please give me some guidance?

Comment: are you trying to use screensharing on http and not https? That won't work.

Comment: No I need to use it over https, is Firefox capable of doing this? I developed the code but it didn't work till I change this flag even over https, this error is always shown when I try to access this api navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Comment: Firefox will not allow sharing the screen over http for security reasons. It may also reject inside iframes.

Comment: Just FYI screen sharing is a lot more dangerous then accessing the camera. See https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/share-browser-windows-entire-screen-sites-trust/

Comment: If you're talking about localhost why do you need to change the prefs from JS?