# prompt the user to change about:config flags in Firefox

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I'm trying to add screen-sharing feature in my app using webrtc and Firefox browser,I'm facing the same error that described here:
[Twilio screensharing on localhost in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497849/twilio-screensharing-on-localhost-in-firefox)

The problems is that I need to set the flag(**media.navigator.permission.disabled**) to make the screen sharing work but for security reasons we can't do that in the code, what I'm trying to do is to make Firefox prompt the user to change this flag.

 
Is this possible? can we make Firefox prompt the user to change this flag?
any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to prompt them to disable a global flag rather than just ask permission to use their screen?

Comment: @George Yeah, that looks like it a lot x)

Comment: @Nathan I'm saying that this is possible or not! I'm just asking! no need to vote down the questions guys you can ignore it!

Comment: yes George I want to  prompt him to enable this flag if it is possible.

Comment: As others have said, your best bet is to play nicely and let Firefox ask the user for the permission to share their screen.

Comment: @MahmoudAbdALKareem Didn't downvote it, your question is clear. IT doesn't matter to me if it's the __good__ way to do it, this diferentiation is mandatory in an answer, not in the question. Your question is ok AFAIC.

Answer (score 3):

For security purposes there is no way for JS code to change flags. Giving JS code the ability to do that would have really dangerous implications.

Screen sharing is only allowed on HTTPS origins. So you really need to get your self a certificate for your test page, e.g. from Lets Encrypt.